# vertexInfo properties in ArcGIS JS 4x API for event when reshaping polygon

Tags: polygon, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, vertices

When dragging a polygon vertex using the `Sketch` class, the `update` event is fired, with a `type` of "reshape".

**4X:**

```
sketch.on("update", onGraphicUpdate);
    
function onGraphicUpdate(event) {
      if (event.toolEventInfo && event.toolEventInfo.type === "reshape") {
        console.warn(toolEventInfo);
        //this does not seem to have any info about the vertex being dragged, even though we have the 
        //polygon 
      }
}
```

Previously in 3x, we could grab a `vertexInfo` object off of that type of event (vertex-move), which contained the `pointIndex` and `segmentIndex` of that vertex.

**3X:**

```
editToolbar.on('vertex-move',function(evt){
   console.log(evt.vertexInfo.pointIndex);
});
```

Does anyone know if `pointIndex` and `segmentIndex` exist anywhere, or how to decipher/identify which vertex within the polygon is actively being moved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**toolEventInfo.selected**

This does not seem to be documented anywhere (as of 4.18, even if using the 4x typings), but through debugging, I was able to find `pathIndex` (previously `segmentIndex`) and `pointIndex` in the event fired from `sketch.update`

```
sketch.on("update", (event) => {
    const toolEventInfo = event.toolEventInfo;
    if (toolEventInfo && toolEventInfo.type === "reshape") {
        //reshape event types should have a "selected" prop containing info about the 
        //vertex being edited
        const { pathIndex, pointIndex } = event.toolEventInfo.selected[0].attributes;
    }
});
```